# Is there a way to initialize properties after construction of object?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, object-initializers

I have a `Conversion` class like this:

```
public class Conversion
{
    public memorySource MSource { get; set; }
    public Rule[] Rules { get; set; }
    public Conversion(XElement xElement)
    {
       // I use Rules property here 
       // From Rules property and xElement parameter i initialize MSource Property
    }

    public Conversion(ExcelPackage)
    {
       // Also i use Rules property here 
       // From Rules property and xElement parameter i initialize MSource Property
    }
}
```

When I want to construct an instance of the `Conversion` class, I do this:

```
Conversion cvr = new Conversion(xElement) { Rules = rules };
```

Then I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I know that construction of object begins before initializing of properties, but is there a way to do inverse?

I can use Rules property as parameter of constructor but it is not suitable for performance because I have several constructors.

Comment: you have to initialize rules in the constructor or add another constructor that takes Rules as you said. there is no other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply pass the value as parameter in the constructor. It's the only way:

```
Conversion cvr = new Conversion(rules, package);
```

Where the constructor is:

```
public Conversion(Rule[] rules, ExcelPackage package)
{
   this.Rules = rules;

   ...
}
```

You can default the `rules` parameter for your other constructor, so you don't have to duplicate code:

```
public Conversion(ExcelPackage package) : this(new Rule[] { ... }, package)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you've already shown an example with `: this` so I removed mine.

Comment: the way OP doing is not possible??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Not if you intend to use `Rules` inside the constructor. Object initializers are post-constructor actions.

Comment: @PatrickHofman i studied in Albahari book and what i remember we can write that way

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: You can, but that will initialize the `Rules` **after** the constructor. OP needs the `Rules` **in** the constructor.

Comment: The order is Class initialization => Constructor initialization

Comment: @Bouam: And then object intializers. That's where this question is about.